# Can you post to Wordpress with cURL with XML-RPC disabled?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, xml-rpc

I have a bunch of Wordpress blogs and I would like to turn off the XML-RPC on all of them for security reasons. The problem is when I do this I can't use my custom WP management application anymore. Is there any other way I can log in and post to Wordpress using PHP? cURL or any other option? Has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use cURL or any other solution, it is in the end the same as if you would use the built in XML-RPC solution. So if there is a security reason to disable XML-RPC, then any other solution does bring you the same *risks*.

You could limit the XML-RPC to accept requests only from a specific host/ip. Probably from `localhost` and then tunnel via SSH or VPN to your server to post via a secure connection.